# Adding a UIImageView to a Table View in Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I want to add an ImageView to the bottom of my Table View (in a fixed position over the cells) so that I can place a custom tab bar there. However, when I drag the Image View to the Table view in Storyboard it attaches itself to the bottom of the prototype cells. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an imageview, slect your tableView ViewController in the storyboard, and in the simulated metrics section of the Utilities pane (right pane), select Tab Bar for the "bottom bar" setting.

Then you can drag your tabBarItems to the simulated tab bar.

[image]